# How to show random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ eventually never enters unit sphere?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

I cam across this problem and cannot figure out how to approach or solve it:

Given the random walk $(S_n^z)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ starting at $z \in \mathbb{Z}^3$ with uniform distribution on its neighbors. Let $\mathbb{P}_z$ be the probability if we start from a point $z \in \mathbb{Z}^3$. I already know that the random walk is transient for every starting point $z$. But is it also true, that
$$\limsup_{|z| \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}_z(\cap_{t \in \mathbb{N}}\{|S_t| > 1\})=1,$$
i.e. that there exist starting points arbitrary far away such that we never enter the units sphere?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In $\mathbb Z^3$ the "unit sphere" only has $7$ points, which simplifies the problem

Comment: In fact, a stronger result is true; you can replace $\limsup$ with $\liminf$ and the statement still holds. Are you able to prove the result (even the $\limsup$ version) by replacing "the unit sphere" with "the origin"? That result is equivalent and may be simpler to show.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery What I managed to do is the following: Since the random walk is transient, we have that $\mathbb{P}_z(\cup_{t_0 \in \mathbb{N}}\cap_{t \geq t_0} \{S_t \neq z\}) = 1$ and therefore we have $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}_z(\cup_{t \geq t_0} \{S_t \neq z\})=1$. Which implies that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $t_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $t \geq t_0$ we have $\mathbb{P}_z(\cup_{t \geq t_0} \{S_t \neq z\}) \geq 1-\epsilon$. I cannot see how to proceed from here:/